# Drupal 7 - Node Gallery visible for logged users only

Tags: drupal, permissions, drupal-7, gallery

1. I have Drupal 7 with NodeGallery installed. I have several galleries in on my website.
2. Some of those galleries are linked to the main menu items and always visible and some of those are linked to menu items visible only after the user has signed up.
3. But when someone is logged-in and for example sends a link to gallery (like http://my.site.com/?q=node/1477), that is hidden for external (unlogged) users, they see that gallery, although they don't see it in main menu.

The option in Content management (for this gallery) "Is private" and the combo box "Authenticated only" has no effect (has effect only with the visibility of the link in main menu). If someone knows the link, he has access to the gallery. That is not desirable.

How can the permissions of view of the concrete gallery be restricted to only authenticated user?

Answer (score 0):

For controlling the logged in and logged out menu items you can use menu item visibility module URL: https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_item_visibility where you can control which menu item is visible to which role.

And you can use hook_node_view hook to check which node(s) to be visible to which roles of user or you can use nodeaccess module to have a backend to make your node visible to which user URL: https://www.drupal.org/project/nodeaccess

Thanks

Comment: Thanks. I have nodeaccess installed, but the gallery doesn't seem to care about privacy settings, that have been set there. When it is about "menu item visibility", I need to restrict access to the gallery (not its link in menu, but the gallery itself). For example, if I send someone the link to the gallery, it can be invisible in menu, but anyone, that has no account, can view the gallery with that link.
    
The hook_node_view, however, seems interesting. I'll check this trail.